# Access button class in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button class that is placed inside an iframe. Problem is that this button's class has such a long name and I do not understand how to reference it in my script.

```
<button class="PDF-dmzpd5z6ckdkxkn8 PDF-5rbqp8nfgh6e11 PDF-tma5quj Toolbar-Button Tool-Button" title="SignUp" aria-label="myButton001" type="button"></button>
```

I am using my javascript to reference this class as:

```
document.querySelector("iframe").contentWindow.document.querySelector(".PDF-dmzpd5z6ckdkxkn8").click();
```

The above code does not work. Do I have to provide the complete class name for reference?

I am on right track because I have another button that looks like this:

```
<button class="PDF-tdsfethgr51stg Next-Button Next-Previous-Button" title="Next" aria-label="Next" type="button"></button>
```

And I can easily call/reference it via:

```
document.querySelector("iframe").contentWindow.document.querySelector(".PDF-tdsfethgr51stg").click();
```

Comment: Those buttons have no [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) at all.

Comment: @tevemadar sorry I meant class name

Comment: Are you sure the content is already loaded when the script is executed? The iframe might have dynamic elements being added asynchronously.

Comment: Those look like class-names generated by React or some other runtime framework. If you're bypassing that framework and manipulating the DOM directly then you'll likely run into issues. Please tell us **where** your script is running and if React.js or some other framework (Vue.js?) is being used.

Comment: What errors/output do you see in your browser console?

Comment: It's not the cause of your problem, but you can use `contentDocument` rather than `contentWindow.document` if you wish to be a little more concise.

Comment: Also you may check that only your target button has class `.PDF-dmzpd5z6ckdkxkn8`. I would suggest you to use more specific rule - something like `button.PDF-dmzpd5z6ckdkxkn8`.

Comment: @Dai might be up to something, I suspect cross-origin policy issues. Otherwise it's either the timing (you could try if postponing your code using `iframe.onload = ` for example works) or classnames are changing as said.

Comment: Thank you for all your replies. I would like to say that I am doing a javascript injection for a web html page. I have no control on the html part of the code since that is completely external.

Comment: @royarisse if it was a cross-origin policy, then the second button which I am injecting should also not work right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If selecting with class doesn't work, you can try to select with title attribute:

```
document.querySelector('button[title="SignUp"]');
```

Comment: Thank you. That actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

Using Id in button is the best option

**Example**:

```
<button class="PDF-dmzpd5z6ckdkxkn8 PDF-5rbqp8nfgh6e11 PDF-tma5quj Toolbar-Button Tool-Button" title="SignUp" aria-label="myButton001" type="button" id="exbtn1"></button>
```

```
document.querySelector("iframe").contentWindow.document.querySelector("#exbtn1").click();
```

**Note: It's best option to define the tags in Query Selector (eg. document.querySelector("iframe")[0]). The index starts from 0.**

Comment: Thank you but I have no control over the HTML elements. I am using javascript injection to trigger it.